# Adding attributes to cells using footable

Tags: javascript, jquery, footable

I am using footables ajax capability, and I am stumped on how to add attributes to the individual  tags.  For instance, in the docs, there is a data-sort-value attribute that can be set.  With a static table, I can use `<td data-sort-value="1">foo</td>`.

I found that I can add data attributes to the `<th>` elements by putting them in the columns json file.  For instance, in the following file, anything that isn't "name" or "title" is put in as a data element, such as "breakpoints", in the JSON below, is inserted into the `<th>` tag as `<th data-breakpoints="xs sm">...</th>`

```
[
    {"breakpoints":"xs sm","name":"id","title":"Employee ID"},
    {"name":"full_name","title":"Name"},
    {"name":"phone","title":"Phone"},
    {"breakpoints":"sm xs","name":"email","title":"Email"},
    {"breakpoints":"xs","type":"html","name":"working","title":"Available"},
    {"breakpoints":"sm xs","type":"html","name":"actions","title":"Actions"}
]
```

The documentation is severely lacking about the format of the JSON it receives, and editing these things afterwards isn't an option without knowing what value is already in each column.

I am assuming, if this is possible, it is something that would go in the rows JSON file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After racking my brain on this for a while, and reading through the docs, I figured out how all of this works, although it could be explained better in their docs.

With footables, there are options you can put in the JSON.  When you do this, you can access all the options available, and not just this one.  In the instant case, the following worked:

```
{
    "id": 16,
    "full_name": "John Doe",
    "phone": "555-555-5555"
    "email": "john@doe.com",
    "working": {
        "options": {
            "sortValue": "1"
        },
        "value": "<span class =\"green fa fa-check-circle\"> </span>"
    },
    "actions": "..."
},
...
```

You can add new options under "options", and then your value is just inserted for your value.